# Code for printf function in C

Tags: c, printf, stdio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [source code of c/c++ functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127328/source-code-of-c-c-functions)

I was wondering where I can find the C code that's used so that when I write printf("Hello World!"); in my C programm to know that it has to print that string to STDOUT. I looked in <stdio.h>, but there I could only find its prototype int printf(const char *format, ...), but not how it looks like internally.

Comment: From which implementation? Each platform has its own...

Comment: I don't think there's the source available. +1 anyway, I always wondered this.

Comment: Ultimately printf has to make an OS call so the exact implementation is platform specific. Following the trail from printf down to the actual OS call(s) can be pretty messy. The source for the C-Runtime Library (CRT) is usually available with the compiler (true for GCC and MSVC).

Comment: related - [Understanding the hardware of printf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2457656/203667) & [C/C++ function definitions without assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2442966/203667)

Comment: `printf` is defined in terms of `putc` so there's no need for it to make any OS calls.

Comment: @R..: Typically, it's not possible to perform **any** I/O without making operating system calls. While you can talk directly to hardware or via BIOS, modern operating systems prevent you from doing so.

Comment: @Tergiver, @R: You're both right.  `printf` handles formatting, then calls `putc`, which may call other helper functions but ultimately results in an OS call.

Comment: My point was that the OS calls are at a much lower level, and `printf` is essentially a pure library function on top of lower-level stdio calls.

Comment: Funny how this, a more specific question, triggering more specific answers, is higher-rated and perhaps more useful than the original question which caused this question to be "closed as a duplicate".

Answer (score 98):

Here's the GNU version of `printf`... you can see it passing in `stdout` to `vfprintf`:

```
__printf (const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   int done;

   va_start (arg, format);
   done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
   va_end (arg);

   return done;
}
```

[See here.](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/printf.c;h=4c8f3a2a0c38ab27a2eed4d2ff3b804980aa8f9f;hb=3321010338384ecdc6633a8b032bb0ed6aa9b19a)

Here's [a link](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;h=fc370e8cbc4e9652a2ed377b1c6f2324f15b1bf9;hb=3321010338384ecdc6633a8b032bb0ed6aa9b19a) to `vfprintf`... all the formatting 'magic' happens here.

The only thing that's truly 'different' about these functions is that they use varargs to get at arguments in a variable length argument list. Other than that, they're just traditional C. (This is in contrast to Pascal's `printf` equivalent, which is implemented with specific support in the compiler... at least it was back in the day.)

Comment: Where is this file located under my linux system. I'm using RHEL. Thanks!

Comment: @Jerry Its object code is in your libc. Download the glibc source code for the source.

Comment: one of the most well-known library functions, and what's in [line 98 of its source code](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;h=fc370e8cbc4e9652a2ed377b1c6f2324f15b1bf9;hb=3321010338384ecdc6633a8b032bb0ed6aa9b19a#l98)? bunch of `goto` and "This is a hack!!!" ;)