# How does C know the output string size of printf?

Tags: c

```
printf("%s%d%c", s, a, c);
```

The string would be printed on the stdout; but how the implementation knows to define what 
size of the char array to hold result?

Or the alternative way is: use the fixed size buffer, handle each variable argument behind the format string, if the interpreted string size exceed the buffer size, then output it to output stream. Is this true?

By the way, I think, the string type in C++, its implementation uses the heap memory, dynamic memory allocator, just as `new`, or `delete`, is this correct?

Comment: There are lots of open source implementations around.  Why not just go look at one?

Comment: Why do you think that there is necessarily a "char array to hold the result"?

Comment: Maybe there isn't, and printf just writes one byte after another diectly to file descriptor 1...

Comment: There are many ways of implementing this, eg, just streaming the chars out, or reallocating if the buffer is too short.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367511/unlimited-buffer-printf-formatted-puts-directly-to-stream

Comment: Well, the c library I/O function is buffered, not write byte directly to stdout, that's the way of read/write sys call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The string would be printed on the stdout

That's correct.  Which is a *stream*, no char[] is required.  Only sprintf() would require a guess at a string buffer size.

Comment: The last sentence is *slightly* misleading since `sprintf` doesn’t take care of the buffer itself. The *caller* needs to know how large the buffer is. Of course they never do, they just use a fixed-size buffer. :p

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So Am I right about c++ string implementation, that the string is implemented as heap allocated memory by new/delete?

Comment: The std::string class is a library implementation detail, every compiler has its own library.  Mine doesn't start using the heap until the string gets large enough.  This otherwise has nothing to do with printf(), maybe you ought to ask another question about it.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have explained, `printf` doesn't need to know the size of some output buffer ahead of time because it doesn't need to allocate one when writing to a `FILE*` stream.

However, you might then wonder: what about functions in the `printf`-family that *don't* write to `FILE*` streams?  What about, say, the non-standard `asprintf` function that returns an allocated string?

The underlying implementation for the `printf` family of functions can do a dry-run.  That is, it can simulate doing the operation without actually writing to memory and keep track of the number of `char`s that it *would have* written.  Once it computes the that number, it then can allocate a buffer of the appropriate size and repeat the operation for real.  This is what a caller would do when it needs to allocate a buffer itself, such as when calling `snprintf`.

(You also talk about buffered I/O.  While `printf` can use that, `printf` doesn't necessarily know about the buffer itself (and it probably shouldn't).  You can think of it as calling `fputc` a bunch of times, which then writes the `char` to some buffer, flushing it if it's full.)

Answer (score 0):

> but how the implementation knows to define what size of the char array
>   to hold result

Just reads up to null terminating byte `'\0'`. No need to explicitely know the size of the `"%s%d%c"` which is passed in as a `char *`