# GCC reports lots of warnings while using varargs in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Here is my code snippet: [[Full Code]](https://raw.github.com/kevin-dong-nai-jia/Console-Snake/master/Console-Snake%20v1.9.0a.c)

```
void Draw_Square (HDC DeviceContext, int Cnt, ...)
{
    int Cnt_1, Cnt_2, Cnt_3, Cnt_4;
    for (Cnt_1 = 0; Cnt_1 < 4; Cnt_1++)
    {
        for (Cnt_2 = 0; Cnt_2 < 6; Cnt_2++)
        {
            va_list Ap;
            va_start (Ap, (Cnt*4));
            for (Cnt_3 = 0; Cnt_3 < Cnt; Cnt++)
                Draw_Line (DeviceContext, (Cnt_1*6+Cnt_2), va_arg (Ap, short), va_arg (Ap, short), va_arg (Ap, int), va_arg (Ap, COLORREF));
            va_end (Ap);
        }
        Sleep (User_Def_Delay);
    }
}
```

GCC/mingw32 reported:

```
|   |In function 'Draw_Square':                                                              |
|393|warning: second parameter of 'va_start' not last named argument [enabled by default]    |
|395|warning: 'short int' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...' [enabled by default]|
|395|note: (so you should pass 'int' not 'short int' to 'va_arg')                            |
|395|note: if this code is reached, the program will abort                                   |
|395|warning: 'short int' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...' [enabled by default]|
|395|note: if this code is reached, the program will abort                                   |
```

Why? wrong type?

Thanks.

**Added:**

I've modified my code, but it is still failed.

```
void Draw_Square (HDC DeviceContext, int Cnt, ...)
{
 va_list Ap;
 va_start (Ap, Cnt);
 int Cnt_1, Cnt_2, Cnt_3;
 for (Cnt_1 = 0; Cnt_1 < 4; Cnt_1++)
 {
  for (Cnt_2 = 0; Cnt_2 < 6; Cnt_2++)
  {
   for (Cnt_3 = 0; Cnt_3 < Cnt; Cnt++)
    Draw_Line (DeviceContext, (Cnt_1*6+Cnt_2), (short)va_arg (Ap, int), (short)va_arg (Ap, int), va_arg (Ap, int), va_arg (Ap, COLORREF));
  }
  Sleep (User_Def_Delay);
 }
 va_end (Ap);
}
```

and get no warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The order of argument-evaluation is undefined so your multiple calls to `va_arg` in the argument-list to `Draw_Line` can happen in any order, that is probably a (if not *the*) problem.
2. The second parameter to `va_start` **must** be `Cnt` (the last parameter to your function), it can't be `Count` as you have. This is what your compiler is warning you about.

   Note that the value of that parameter does not matter, `va_start` needs it to know where to start processing the variable-arguments.

As Kerrek SB mentioned the way you're using variable-arguments here isn't the way they're supposed to be used. Since the arguments are mandatory anyway you may as well give them named parameters in you `Draw_Line` function. It is also even dangerous: if there are less than 4 of the variable-arguments provided the calls to `va_arg` will cause undefined behaviour. That won't happen if the parameters are named parameters since the compiler will raise an insufficient-number-of-arguments error.

**ADDIT**: You seem to be under the assumption that the varargs macros & functions keep track of how many variable-arguments there are / how many they expect. They don't: you need to keep track of them. Which is why your calls to va_arg can cause undefined behaviour if there are less variable-arguments than you expect.

`va_start` needs the last named (or last parameter with a known type) parameter so that it knows where to start extracting the variable-arguments but it doesn't need to know how many there are.

See also C99 §7.15.1.4 p 4 (`va_start`):

> The parameter parmN is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in the variable
>   parameter list in the function definition (the one just before the , ...). If the parameter
>   parmN is declared with the register storage class, with a function or array type, or
>   with a type that is not compatible with the type that results after application of the default argument promotions, the behavior is undefined.

and §7.15.1.1 p 2 (`va_arg`):

> [...] If there is no actual next argument, or if
>   type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according
>   to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, [...]

Comment: Can't it be `va_start (Ap, (Cnt*4));` ?

Comment: No, it must be just the last named parameter. But why would you want it to be `Cnt*4`? That makes no sense, `va_start` doesn't use the value of that parameter, just its name.

Comment: the second parameter means the amount of arguments it'll get, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it is just the last named parameter of the function, regardless of what that parameter means. The varargs macros & functions don't keep track of how many variable-arguments there are or how many they expect. That is up to you. Which is why your calls to `va_arg` can cause undefined behaviour if there are less variable-arguments than you expect.

Comment: I think the second parameter means the amount of argument it'll get. (Maybe I am wrong.) [Here is the example on GNU Website](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html#Variadic-Example). It passes 3 and 10 to `add_em_up()`!

Comment: An understandable mistake, it often is the number of variable-arguments as the function does need to know that. But look for example at [`printf`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4867288/249237) here the last named parameter is a `const char *`, definitely not a number, but it is passed to `va_start` directly. (`v`)`printf` then extracts the number of arguments it should be getting from the format. But `va_start` doesn't concern itself with this.

Comment: If so, is the second parameter meaningless?

Comment: I've solved this problem. Here is my [solution](https://github.com/kevin-dong-nai-jia/Console-Snake/blob/master/Console-Snake%20v1.9.0.c#L396-L400)  Appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Read the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/stdarg.h.html). You want something like this:

```
void Draw_Square (HDC DeviceContext, int Cnt, ...)
{
    va_list Ap;
    va_start(Ap, Cnt);

    // ... loop can use "va_arg" repeatedly

    va_end(Ap);
}
```

Generally, it doesn't make sense to pass mandatory arguments like your `Cnt_1`, ..., `Cnt_4` as variable arguments. Just make then normal arguments. There are *sometimes* situations where variable ar­gu­ments make sense for fixed arguments (e.g. when you implement the Linux system call interface), but that's rare, error prone and more of a last-resort than good design. But if you must, you can always do it:

```
    // prologue as above

    short Cnt_1 = va_args(Ap, int);
    short Cnt_2 = va_args(Ap, int);
    short Cnt_3 = va_args(Ap, int);
    short Cnt_4 = va_args(Ap, int);

    // loop

    // epilogue
```

Furthermore, you cannot pass integers as anything shorter than `int` as variable arguments, since they will always get standard-promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`. So `va_args(Ap, short)` is never correct, and it should be `va_args(Ap, int)`: The conversion `short` to `int` to `short` is well defined and preserves the original value.

To stress that last point: If you were to pass an `unsigned short`, you would need to va-cast to `unsigned int`:

```
unsigned short n = va_args(Ap, unsigned int);
```

This would be fine no matter whether on your platform the `unsigned short` is default-promoted to `int` *or* `unsigned int` (both are possible; this is platform dependent): As the linked documentation says, this is well-defined as long as both versions are sign-variants of one another and the *value* in question is representable by both types. This is indeed the case: If the `unsigned short` is promoted to `int`, then its value must automatically also be representable by an `unsigned int`, since unsigned types can represent all the non-negative values of their signed counterparts.

Comment: I've modified my code, but it is still failed. why? thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: @KVD: OK, right, but `va_start` needs to get the actual function parameter (sorry, not enough coffee yet on my end).