# Duplicating a function with a new name

Tags: c, glibc

I am making a C library that creates a print function, which basically executes printf. Because of this, I wish to create a duplicate of printf from glibc, but with the name print. How can I duplicate this function without duplicating all of it's code?

(I found the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867229/code-for-printf-function-in-c) but don't understand how to duplicate it in my library, or if it is legal to do so.)

Comment: The initial question was `println` with `'\n'`, now you changed that one day after and all the answers look wrong!.

Comment: I think the question was always intended to mean what it says now, but the original wording was confusing.  Lots of people appear to have misunderstood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void println(const char* format,...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,format);
    vprintf(format,args);
    printf("\n");
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variadic macro:

```
#define println(...)  (printf(__VA_ARGS__), (void) puts(""))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a Macro:

```
#define print  printf
```

or define a wrapper function

```
int print( char *fmt, ... )
{
     va_list ap;
     int n;

     va_start(ap, fmt);
     n = vprintf(fmt, ap);
     va_end(ap);

     return n;
}
```

Comment: Neither of these do what the OP asked for.

Comment: @chris I believe he asked for "I wish to create a duplicate of printf from glibc, but with the name print."

Comment: *which basically executes printf with a \n appended to the string*

Comment: _I am making a C library that creates a *println* function, which basically executes printf with a \n appended to the string. Because of this, I wish ..._

Comment: Where is the appended `'\n'` in your two proposals?

Comment: Heh, maybe the question should be edited for clarity.

Comment: sorry, the \n wasn't really intended to be part of the question. I'll remove it.