# definition of function printf in C language

Tags: c

I have read that C language does not include instructions for input and for output and that printf, scanf, getchar, putchar are actually functions.

Which are the primitive C language instructions to obtain the function printf , then?
Thank you.

Comment: did you try to mean `system calls`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for printf function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867229/code-for-printf-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `printf`, you have to `#include <stdio.h>`. That file declares the function.

If you where thinking about how printf is implemented: printf might internally call any other functions and probably goes down to `putc` (also part of the C runtime) to write out the characters one-by-one. Eventually one of the functions needs to really write the character to the console. How this is done depends on the operating system. On Linux for example `printf` might internally call the Linux `write` function. On Windows `printf` might internally call `WriteConsole`.

Comment: In an embedded system I've seen `printf` calling `putc`. The implementation of `putc` was left to the developer, i.e. I had to write the `putc` and decide what it should mean in my system. For instance it could be a written to a uart or any other device in the system.

Comment: @nielsen: `putc()` is in itself a function defined by the standard library. If the implementation of `putc()` is left to the developer, that means it does not provide a fully conforming library implementation. That's not a bad thing, mind -- the standard explicitly allows for only a subset of the standard headers being provided ("freestanding" environment).

Comment: @Nielsen I know, printf does not directly call write or WriteConsole. I thought my answer would be easier if I abstract from this. But as you are right I now changed my answer to be more technically correct.

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks for the answer. This might be a dumb question but when you mention "Linux `write` function...Window `WriteConsole`", are `write` and `WriteConsole` themselves system calls (i.e. invoke kernel routines) or they are just other provided library APIs?

Comment: @torez233 From my understanding `write` is a Linux system call and `WriteConsole` is part of the Windows API (library( and internally calls the `NtWriteFile` system call (compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228469/1023911).

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks. For the `write` system call, I'm curious if this call is actually backed by assembly code or still written in C? I know C itself is a pretty low-level language and I'm curious if its API in the end is implemented in assembly then translated into machine code or directly translated into machine code

Answer (score 1):

The function `printf` is documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/); in fact, it is not part of the C language itself. The language itself does not provide a means for input and output. The function `printf` is defined in a library, which can be accessed using the compiler directive `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: It should be noted that the standard library is defined in the same document as the rest of the lanugage.

Answer (score 1):

**No programming language provides true "primitives" for I/O.** Any I/O "primitives" rely on lower abstraction levels, in this language or another.

I/O, at the lowest level, needs to access hardware. You might be looking at BIOS interrupts, hardware I/O ports, memory-mapped device controlers, or something else entirely, depending on the actual hardware your program is running on.

Because it would be a real burden to cater for all these possibilities *in the implementation of the programming language*, a *hardware abstraction layer* is employed. Individual I/O controllers are accessed by hardware drivers, which in turn are controlled by the operating system, which is providing I/O services to the application developer through a defined, abstract API. These may be accessed directly (e.g. by user-space assembly), or wrapped further (e.g. by the implementation of a programming language's interpreter, or standard library functions).

Whether you are looking at "commands" like (bash) `echo` or (Python) `print`, or library functions like (Java) `System.out.println()` or (C) `printf()` or (C++) `std::cout`, is just a syntactic detail: Any I/O is going through several layers of abstraction, because it is easier, and because it protects you from all kinds of erroneous or malicious program behaviour.

Those **are** the "primitives" of the respective language. If you're digging down further, you are leaving the realm of the language, and enter the realm of its *implementation*.

---

I once worked on a C library implementation myself. Ownership of the project has [passed on](http://pdclib.e43.eu) since, but basically it worked like this:

- `printf()` was implemented by means of `vfprintf()` (as was, eventually, every function of the `*printf()` family).
- `vfprintf()` used a couple of internal helpers to do the fancy formatting, writing into a buffer.
- If the buffer needed to be flushed, it was passed to an internal `writef()` function.
- this `writef()` function needed to be implemented differently for each target system. On POSIX, it would call `write()`. On Win32, it would call `WriteFile()`. And so on.