# What system call(s) does printf() use inorder to write data to the console in Windows?

Tags: c, windows

What exact system call(s) does printf() use in order to write data to the console in Windows ? And, are they located in ntdll.dll or kernel32.dll or both or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

`printf` doesn't write the data directly to the console, it writes data to the output stream. It's the [console host](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/07/20/windows-command-line-inside-the-windows-console/) (`conhost.exe`) that takes the data from the output stream and writes it to the console.

There is an [entire API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) for accessing the console. For example, the [`WriteConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) function.

Comment: Whether the communications channel is through the ConDrv device (Windows 8+) or an LPC port and shared memory (prior to Windows 8), the channel / device / port itself doesn't implement the console buffers. Those are implemented in the conhost.exe process (or csrss.exe prior to Windows 7). There are matching server-side functions such as `conhost!ApiDispatchers::ServerWriteConsole` (they've been rewriting a lot in C++; this all used to be just C) that dispatch an I/O request received either via `NtDeviceIoControlFile` or, in older versions, whatever LPC system call is used.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by zdan, `printf` doesn't write directly to the console, but writes to the standard output stream with [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) Windows API, which in turn calls the [`NtWriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntwritefile) system call. Then the output data is picked up by the Console Host `conhost.exe` and displayed to the Windows Console.

Comment: NT I/O calls (e.g. `NtReadFile`, `NtWriteFile`, `NtDeviceIoControlFile`) are used in Windows 8+, which switched to the ConDrv device. Previously, `WriteFile` routed operating on a console buffer handle (i.e. the value has the lower 2 bits set) to an internal implementation shared with `WriteConsole`. It used the process `ConsoleHandle` (in this case an LPC port handle) to talk to the console host. This channel was in part based on shared memory overlayed by a heap. (This is the 'heap' that the console docs sometimes mention; all limits related to it do not exist in Windows 8+.)