# C putchar doesn't work after stdout is redirected

Tags: c, shell, stdout, putchar

I am trying to implement shell redirection, using this I redirect stdout to fd1

```
int redirectOut(int fd1)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    int fd2 = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(fd1, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd1);
    return fd2;
}
```

I then fork and call an executable, it works except in the case where the executable uses putchar.

On the putchar man page it is written that it uses stdout.

> putchar(c); is equivalent to putc(c,stdout).

Why doesn't putchar write anywhere neither in the standard output nor the file I redirected the stream to ?

I tried changing *putchar* to *putc* but it didn't help, it might have something to do with the fact that **stdout** if a ***FILE** and **STDOUT_FILENO** an **int**

How can I make my code work and why does it work with printf which uses ([code for printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867229/code-for-printf-function-in-c))

```
done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
```

**EDIT MORE CODE**

```
int executeBlocs(execBloc *bloc,int fileIn,int fileOut){
    if(bloc->first != NULL){
      if (strcmp(bloc->ope, ">") == 0){
         int out = open(bloc->command[0], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC , 0644);
         int returnCode = executeBlocs(bloc->first, STDIN_FILENO, out);
         redirectOut(fileOut);
         redirectIn(fileIn);
         return returnCode;
      }
    }
    else{
        redirectIn(fileIn);
        redirectOut(fileOut);
        return call(bloc->nbWords, bloc->command);
    }
}
```

execBloc is a struct that contains a command to execute (or a file name) an operator (>> , | , > ...) and a reference to the another bloc that contains the rest of the command.

If the user enter **cat /tmp/testCat > /tmp/testCatRedirection**

then a first structure will be created containing the operator *>* and the command */tmp/testCatRedirection* and first which is a reference to the second structure containing the command *cat /tmp/testCat*

```
int call(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 0){
      if (executeProgram(argv) == 1) return 1;

      if (executeStandardLibrary(argc, argv) == 1) return 1;

      if (executeDynamicLibrary(argc, argv) == 1) return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}


int executeProgram(char const *argv[]){
    //Creation de la chaine de caractère /home/kerdam/cbin/nonExecutable
    char *path = strdup(binFolder);
    strcat(path, argv[0]);


    //Test si le fichier existe et est executable
    if (access(path, F_OK|X_OK) != -1){
    //Le fichier existe et on peut l'éxecuter
    int pid = fork();

    // Error
    if (pid == -1){
      return -1;
    }
    //Fils
    else if (pid == 0) {
        // Executer la commande
        execv(path, argv);
        return 1;
    }

    // Parent process
    else {
        // Wait for child process to finish
        int childStatus;
        waitpid(pid, &childStatus, 0);
        return 1;
    }
  }
  else return -1;
}
```

Finally the code of the program I am trying to execute

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_CHARS 255
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char file_name[MAX_FILE_NAME_CHARS], ch;
    int i;

     /*
      * after creating a.out, rename it as mycat for our own cat command
      * and it usage is same as standard cat command
      */
    if(argc<=1){
        printf("Utiliser cat avec aumoin un argument (un fichier) <nomfichier> \n");
        return 0;
    }

     /*
      * This is for multiple file in argument
      */
    for(i=1; i<=argc;i++){
        strncpy(file_name, argv[i], MAX_FILE_NAME_CHARS);

        fp=fopen(file_name, "r");
        if(fp == NULL) {
           printf("%s: No such file or directory\n", file_name);
           return 0;
        }

        /*
         * read file and feed contents to STDIO
         */
        while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF || ch == '}'){
            putchar(ch);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Remark**

I should not change the code of the executable I am trying to execute as the users of my shell should be able to execute their programs without restriction on what function they can use.

Comment: Which platform are you experimenting on?  Does `putc(c, stdout)` work as expected after switching files?  What about `fputc(c, stdout)`?  On the surface, you are simply changing what file descriptor 0 references; the standard I/O code should continue to work, writing to file descriptor 0.  Are you sure that `fd1` is open for writing?  (I know that sounds silly, but it is necessary to check since we don't have an MCVE ([MCVE]) to work with.)

Comment: Did you check the value of `fileno(stdout)` ? But as Jonathan request we need a [mcve], I answer this question too fast.

Comment: Are you sure you're outputting a newline with the `putchar()` calls?  Could it simply be that it reverts (changes) to fully buffered output when change the file descriptor to refer to a file, so output isn't seen until flushed?  If it is line buffered, a newline may be sufficient; if it is fully buffered, you may need to use `fflush()`.  However, you say `printf()` et al work, which suggests this isn't the issue.

Comment: First of all here, a fixed test program, http://rextester.com/QSD96627, secondly, you still didn't provide a [mcve]. Third, `int out = open(bloc->command[0], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC , 0644);` is suspect don't you want `int out = open(bloc->command[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC , 0644);` ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually I think you are right, the literals in the *printf* contains a newline character at the end and when removed it doesn't work anymore. 
I don't understand how fflush will help me as if I understood the documentation right it removes everything from a Stream

Comment: @Stargateur I know the semantic is far from perfect but no bloc->command[0] is actually what I want, the structure seemed kind of out the scope of my problem here so I didn't put it

Comment: Remember that `fflush(stdout)` writes any pending output to the o/s, rather than keeping it in the standard I/O buffer.  It does so even if there isn't a newline at the end.  That gives you the maximum chance of seeing the output that's lurking in the buffer for `stdout`.  So, `fflush(stdout)` should never do any damage (unless you count slowing down for long enough to ensure the buffer is empty as 'damage') and may help you see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I've been face with the same problem and found the solution.

Look at the code which reads a file `argv[1]` and writes its content to file `argv[2]` without spaces and line feeds.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    printf ("Expected exactly two arguments\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int rd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  if (rd == -1) {
    printf ("Failed to open file %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  int wd = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0666);
  if (wd == -1) {
    printf ("Failed to open file %s\n", argv[2]);
    return 1;
  }

  int temp_in = dup(0);
  int temp_out = dup(1);

  dup2(rd, 0);
  dup2(wd, 1);

  close(rd);
  close(wd);

  int written_bytes = 0;

  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {
      continue;
    }

    putchar(c);
    written_bytes++;
  }

  // The instruction below is critically important, because
  // putchar by default writes char to an internal buffer,
  // so we have to send it to the file descriptor manually
  fflush(stdout);

  dup2(temp_in, 0);
  dup2(temp_out, 1);

  printf ("%d bytes have been written\n", written_bytes);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to read and compare 100 lines of code in order to understand what you did differently? And what *was* the OP's problem at the core?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica it's only 50 lines of code and they are pretty simple. The most valuable line is `fflush(stdout);` and comment above it. Read the whole bunch of code let you completely understand a problem and solution.