# How to read header file in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, header

How do I read a header file?
I tried searching for cstring and I opened it but there were only #def statements 
And it was pretty short so I tried searching for strcpy i found strcpy.cpp
And it was even shorter.
I want to see how they made strcpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see how they made `strcpy`, you need access to the source code of the C library, typically you are gonna have only the header files, in this case `string.h`, and the compiled library which contains the implementation.

You can  look at [source code of c/c++ functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127328/source-code-of-c-c-functions) which discusses nearly the same question.

Comment: This is an excellent comment for a close vote as a duplicate.

Comment: @KenWhite mine is one of the 4 votes, I found the duplicate after I made the answer, and in either case, the first paragraph did feel more answer-y than comment-y

Comment: I usually delete my answers if I find the question is a duplicate, because the question should be closed anyway. No problem; I didn't downvote, I just commented.