# how can get lib functions bodies in C?

Tags: c

As you can see above,I want to know how library functions (like `printf`) are made in C. I am using the borlandC++ compiler.

They are defined in lib files (***.lib), header files only have prototypes.

Lib files cannot be read in text editors.

So, please let me know how they could read?

Comment: Depends on which compiler you use. GCC generally uses glibc, whose source is available at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/

Comment: possible duplicate of [source code of c/c++ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127328/source-code-of-c-c-functions)

Comment: .lib files are compiled binary code and don't contain the source code (just like .exe for executables). The source code for some open source C standard libraries can be found online. For example `printf` in GNU libc: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=libio;h=9b6ae9cab66e6d1e21f072d93255ebaf4d650454;hb=HEAD

Comment: The implementation of `printf`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;hb=HEAD

Comment: Please notice that C++ is not the same thing as C.

Comment: There is no guarantee functions in a .lib file are written in C, it's quite the reverse: a library can be created in lots of different languages. As far as the linker goes, it's only the generate *code* it is interested in, not its source.

Comment: See if your compiler came with the source code for its libraries. If it didn't, there's not much you can do.  (All versions of C++Builder did include this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is a *compiled* language, so the C source code gets translated to binary machine-language code.

Because of that, you can't *see* the actual source code of any given library you have.

If you want to know how it works, you can see if it's an open source library, find the source code of the particular revision that generated the version you're using, and read it.

If it's not open source, you could try decompiling - use a tool that tries to guess what the original source code could have been like for generating the machine code your library has. As you can guess, this is not an accurate process - compiling isn't an isomorphic process - and, as you probably wouldn't have guessed, it could be illegal - but I'm not really sure what conditions it depends on, if any.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I haven't  known libs are already compiled.